# Is there a way to find UMVUE without just guessing?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, estimation, parameter-estimation

We have $(X_1,...,X_n)$ random sample of distribution $N(m,1)$. I need to find UMVUE of $g(m)=e^m$.

The natural guess was that the unbiased estimator which I need to find may be something like $e^T$, where $T=\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$. So I calculated
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{T}]=exp \left[m+\frac{1}{2n}\right]$$
therefore the unbiased estimator that I was looking for is
$g(T)=e^{T-\frac{1}{2n}}.$

My question is: is there a way to get this result in any other way than just guessing?
I considered solving:
$$\mathbb{E}g(T)=e^m$$
so I would get

$$\int\limits_0^\infty g(t) \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{n}}}e^{-\frac{(t-m)^2}{\frac{2}{n}}} dt=e^m$$ but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

What do you think?

Comment: Its hard to find a "procedure" because to my knowledge there are no necessary conditions for an UMVUE estimator. LS theorem provides sufficient conditions but that itself is not informative about how to find such estimator.

Comment: This depends on the specific problem. Here $e^m$ has the form of the MGF of a univariate normal distribution, so it is reasonable to consider a quantity like $E[e^{aT}]$.